# flutter/dart: can't be returned from an async function with return type

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting an error message when displaying UpdateJobApplicationView.

If i comment out the return type of UpdateJobApplicationView, everything works fine.
but i dont want to do that...

what am i doing wrong here?

error message:

```
: Error: A value of type 'CloudJobApplication?' can't be returned from an async function with return type 'Future<CloudJobApplication>' because 'CloudJobApplication?' is nullable and 'Future<CloudJobApplication>' isn't.
lib/…/widgets/update_job_applications_view.dart:75
- 'CloudJobApplication' is from 'package:ijob_clone_app/services/cloud/cloud_job_application.dart' ('lib/services/cloud/cloud_job_application.dart').
package:ijob_clone_app/…/cloud/cloud_job_application.dart:1
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
    return widgetJob;
```

**View that displays all job applications, I don't think there is an issue here**

```
class _JobApplicationsViewState extends State<JobApplicationsView> {
  late final FirebaseCloudStorage _jobsService;
  String get userId => AuthService.firebase().currentUser!.id;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _jobsService = FirebaseCloudStorage();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Your job applications'),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: _jobsService.allJobApplications(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
            case ConnectionState.active:
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                final allJobApplications =
                    snapshot.data as Iterable<CloudJobApplication>;
                return JobApplicationsListView(
                  jobApplications: allJobApplications,
                  onTap: (job) {
                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                      updateJobApplicationRoute,
                      arguments: job,
                    );
                  },
                );
              } else {
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            default:
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**widget displaying jobApplications**

```
class JobApplicationsListView extends StatelessWidget {
  final Iterable<CloudJobApplication>
      jobApplications; // list of jobApplications
  //final JobCallback onDeleteJob;
  final JobCallback onTap;

  const JobApplicationsListView({
    Key? key,
    required this.jobApplications,
    //required this.onDeleteJob,
    required this.onTap,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: jobApplications.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final jobApplication = jobApplications.elementAt(index);

        return ListTile(
          onTap: () {
            onTap(jobApplication);
          },
          title: Text(
            jobApplication.jobApplicationDescription,
            maxLines: 1,
            softWrap: true,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
          trailing: IconButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              final shouldDelete = await showDeleteDialog(context);
              if (shouldDelete) {
                "onDeleteJob(job)";
              }
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

*** note on error: ***
If I comment out the return type of "Future", everything works fine. but I don't want to do that. see code above 'view with error!'

```
createOrGetExistingJob(
      BuildContext context) async {
    final widgetJob = context.getArgument<CloudJobApplication>();

    if (widgetJob != null) {
      _jobApplication = widgetJob;
      _jobDescriptionController.text = widgetJob.jobApplicationDescription;
      return widgetJob;
    }

    return widgetJob;    // ERROR IS THROWN RIGHT HERE!!
  }
```

***view with error!***

```
class UpdateJobApplicationView extends StatefulWidget {
  const UpdateJobApplicationView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UpdateJobApplicationViewState createState() =>
      _UpdateJobApplicationViewState();
}

// https://youtu.be/VPvVD8t02U8?t=90350
class _UpdateJobApplicationViewState extends State<UpdateJobApplicationView> {
  CloudJobApplication? _jobApplication;
  //CloudJob? _job;
  late final FirebaseCloudStorage _jobsService;
  late final TextEditingController _jobDescriptionController;
  late final TextEditingController _jobAreaCodeController;
  late final TextEditingController _jobStateController;
  final currentUser = AuthService.firebase().currentUser!;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _jobsService = FirebaseCloudStorage();
    _jobDescriptionController = TextEditingController();
    _jobAreaCodeController = TextEditingController();
    _jobStateController = TextEditingController();

    super.initState();
  }



  Future<CloudJobApplication> createOrGetExistingJob(
      BuildContext context) async {
    final widgetJob = context.getArgument<CloudJobApplication>();

    if (widgetJob != null) {
      _jobApplication = widgetJob;
      _jobDescriptionController.text = widgetJob.jobApplicationDescription;
      return widgetJob;
    }

    return widgetJob;    // ERROR IS THROWN RIGHT HERE!!
  }




  @override
  void dispose() {
    _deleteJobIfTextIsEmpty();
    _saveJobIfTextNotEmpty();
    _jobDescriptionController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('update job application'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: (() async {
              print('create new job application');
              final job = _jobApplication;
              if (job == null) {
                return;
              }
              final newJobApplication =
                  await _jobsService.createNewJobApplication(
                      jobApplicationDescription: job.jobApplicationDescription,
                      jobCreatorId: currentUser.id,
                      jobId: job.documentId);
              _jobApplication = newJobApplication;
            }),
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: createOrGetExistingJob(context),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.done:
              _setupTextControllerListener();

              // at this point we want to start to listening for changes
              return Column(
                  //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    const Text('Job State'),
                    Text(_jobStateController.text),

                    const SizedBox(height: 10),
                    const Text('Job description'),
                    TextField(
                      controller: _jobDescriptionController,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                      maxLines: null,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Describe job...',
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 10),
                    // const Text('Area code'),
                    // TextField(
                    //   controller: _jobDescriptionController,
                    //   keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    //   maxLines: null,
                    //   decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    //     hintText: 'Describe job...',
                    //   ),
                    // ),
                  ]);
            default:
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here is all the code:: https://github.com/casas1010/flutter_firebase_vendor_management

Comment: What is the return type of `context.getArgument<CloudJobApplication>();`?

Comment: Either your return type needs to be `Future<CloudJobApplication?>` or you need to check that if returned value is `null` and return something else if it is.

Comment: @Apealed if i do

final widgetJob = context.getArgument<CloudJobApplication>();

print(widgetJob);

i get the following to print

Instance of 'CloudJobApplication'

Comment: The instance doesn't matter. It's the function signature that matters

Comment: gosh dont hate me but I tried to find how to do what your asking, and I have not figured it out. i think im suppose to use typedef but I have no clue how to use it here. could you give me another hint on how how i would find the type you are looking for?